# To split the digits values and format them as a title

Tags: php

i create function my own

here is my code

```
input = "JHON";
       
    $remap = [
"a" => '1',
"A" => '1',
"b" => '2',
"B" => '2',
"c" => '3',
"C" => '3',
"J" => '100',
"H" => '10',
"O" => '90',
"N" => '200',
];
  $star =  str_replace(array_keys($remap), $remap, $input);

echo "$star";
```

my code output

```
1001090200
```

i want comma split output

```
(100,10,90,200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the numbers into an array, then use `implode()` to create a string from that.

```
$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    $c = $input[$i];
    $array[] = $remap[$c];
}
$star = "(" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
echo $star;
```

Comment: brother please make clear example for me sir am not understand  how

Comment: I don't understand. I wrote the entire code for you.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: its show ans like this    (1001090200,100,10,90,200)

Comment: Not for me: https://ideone.com/ZjoMZD

Comment: yes great working fine